# Is there a way to add conditions into a COUNT()?

Tags: mysql, select, count

What I want to do is add a COUNT into a query that is joined on several tables, but I only want to count the thing if it meets a specific condition.

I want the count to only count the rows that have a ReceivedDate like so:

```
COUNT(ReceivedDate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00", plpq.PurchaseOrderID) AS OrdersForPart
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to resort to a sub-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you might want to perform some aggregation on the other rows and thus can't just exclude them entirely in the `WHERE` clause.

```
COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN ReceivedDate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
        THEN plpq.PurchaseOrderID 
      END) AS OrdersForPart
```

If this isn't the case the `WHERE` clause is of course the best option.

Comment: This did not provide an accurate count when compared to a standard select.

Comment: @Ben - Have you remembered that `COUNT(plpq.PurchaseOrderID)` will only count values where `plpq.PurchaseOrderID IS NOT NULL`? Use a constant if you don't want that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Just use where.

```
SELECT COUNT(plpq.PurchaseOrderID) AS OrdersForPart FROM ... WHERE ReceivedDate = '000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Should work just fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(plpq.PurchaseOrderID) 
  AS OrdersForPart 
  FROM table 
  WHERE ReceivedDate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```